# How to set a Div to a specified location based on XML data?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

Using XSL I can turn XML data into valid content for a webpage. However I want to do something like:

> 

```
<div id="tagSpot" style="position:absolute; width:20px; height:20px; left:<xsl:value-of select="@xScale"/>; top:<xsl:value-of select="@yScale"/>;">
```

Both xScale and yScale are decimals representing percentages.

However everytime I try to use that line I get tons of syntax errors. Is there a way to pass a XML element into inline css.

The reason for all of this is to set each image at a specified x/y position which is set in the XML file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-attribute-value-template)

```
<div id="tagSpot" style="position:absolute; width:20px; height:20px; left:{@xScale}; top:{@yScale};">
```